Efficiency advantage of C++ 23 static operator()
I'm looking at the motivation for static operator() laid out in this article
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1169r2.html
where they explain that function objects, frequently used in STL algorithms incur the extra cost of storing their this pointer in a register, even if the operator() does not use it.
To this end they give the following code example:
https://godbolt.org/z/ajTZo2
Where running the algorithm to use the function object's static function rather than the non static operator() does indeed produce shorter assembly code. (They run it once with -DSTATIC and once without )
struct X {
    bool operator()(int) const;
    static bool f(int);
};

inline constexpr X x;

int count_x(std::vector<int> const& xs) {
    return std::count_if(xs.begin(), xs.end(),
#ifdef STATIC
    X::f
#else
    x
#endif
    );
}   

However, when I change the functions to actually do something, whether it is to just return true, or compare the parameter to a hard coded value, the differences seem to disappear, and it appears the produced assembly is identical, leaving me still searching for the advantage of a static operator().
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct X {
    bool operator()(int data ) { return data > 5; } ;
    static bool f(int data) { return data > 5; } ;
};

inline constexpr X x;

int count_x(std::vector<int> const& xs) {
    return std::count_if(xs.begin(), xs.end(),
#ifdef STATIC
    X::f
#else
    x
#endif
    );
}

can anyone explain?
Edit:
After posting this question and realizing from the comments that inlining may be the reason for the identical assembly, I changed the code to the following which again makes the assembly for the static version more efficent.
struct X {
    bool operator()(int data ) ;
    static bool f(int data);
};

 __attribute__ ((noinline))  bool X::operator() (int data) {
     { return data > 5; } 
}

 __attribute__ ((noinline)) bool X::f(int data )
     { return data > 5; } 

inline constexpr X x;

int count_x(std::vector<int> const& xs) {
    return std::count_if(xs.begin(), xs.end(),
#ifdef STATIC
    X::f
#else
    x
#endif
    );
}


With non-visible definition (split in several files), compiler won't be able to remove the extra this in non-static case (unless LTO succeeds, but it is harder).

I haven't tried that yet. I suspected inlining, and I've tried defining the functions out of class body, and the assembly is still identical.

In several cpp files?

The original example is basically what Jarod is talking about. Without the bodies in sight when compiling this TU, we can't just omit the extra argument.

What about in the case of static operator lambdas? Seems the bodies would always be in sight. Would I be able to see any difference?

imho expressiveness should be put first, also because often efficiency then follows. Why rely on the compiler optimizing it out when we do not want nor need the instance in the first place? You found one counter example, but if we can have it static, then indepenend of what the optimizer can do, the overhead of the unecessary instance is not present

Does the post contain both a question and answer? Does anything here need answering?

For me, I don't really care that much about "using a register to pass a this pointer". In the grand scheme of things, that doesn't mean anything. Instead, I sometimes just want a static operator() so I can use the () syntax, instead of having a static perform() or something similar -- sometimes, I just want the function call syntax for readability, and at other times I don't.

@ChristianStieber: I'm not sure how meaningful that is though. You can't do Typename(). Well you can, but that means "initialize an object of that type with these parameters" just like always. So it's always going to be called as object(). There's no readability changed by allowing static operator().

If the function gets inlined, then of course it doesn't matter what the actual calling convention is going to be - it got inlined. But the function doesn't get inlined, then you have to emit a call to the function - which is going to end up doing unnecessary work.
That's basically the point of being able to annotate call operators as static. If you don't need an object parameter, just make it clear from the signature that you don't need an object parameter. You can already do this on named functions, it's just that you couldn't do it if your member function happened to be named (). This was an arbitrary restriction that prevented you from clearly expressing your intent.
Plus it makes the compiler's job easier - don't have to optimize out the object parameter if there was never one to begin with. Inlining failures are a death-by-a-thousand-cuts kind of ordeal, so every little bit helps.
(Source: this was my proposal)

thanks. I had considered simply emailing you the question, but thought perhaps here it could be of benefit to others.
